# How to make OAuth2/Zuul redirect user to login page when refresh token expires?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

How does one makes spring/zuul proxy redirect to the OAuth2 authentication endpoint when the refresh token has expired?

Currently what happens is that I get a `BadCredentialsException` in `OAuth2TokenRelayFilter:getAccessToken()` because the refresh token has expired and that gets returned as a HTTP 500 to the browser.

### Architecture

- edge service with `@EnableZuulProxy`, `@EnableOAuth2Sso` performs authentication with Keycloak and proxy calls to the services below
- UI service that serves the user interface, not protected
- main service with `@EnableResourceServer`, expects OAuth2 access token

### Current implementation status

Requesting any Zuul proxy endpoint triggers the authentiation and redirect the browser to Keycloak. Upon successful authentication Keycloak redirect back to the proxy which retrieve both access token and refresh tokens. Then Zuul fulfils the initial endpoint call.

When the access token expires, a new token is retrieved using the refresh token before proxying to services.

In the main service the OAuth2 token is validated before processing API requests.

Everything works apart from that "refresh token expired" condition. This is such a standard case that I must be  missing something obvious.